# Using method that needs parameters without parameters

Tags: c#

I thought that I know most of the simple basics in C# but I came across this code:

```
    static void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
    {
        //....
        subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
    }
    static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        //....
    }
```

So `ProcessMessagesAsync` needs the parameters `Message message, CancellationToken token` but in `subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessageAsync,...` no parameters are passed.

What is happening here? Why are no parameters needed? Why does this work?

Comment: The code is not calling the method, it's passing the method in as a delegate. Note the method name doesn't have the `...()` ending.

Comment: start you reading from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler` expects a `Func<Message,CancellationToken,Task>` parameter. So here, you are actually passing a reference to the `ProcessMessagesAsync` method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.subscriptionclient.registermessagehandler?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you refer to `ProcessMessageAsync` in the call to the `RegisterMessageHandler(` method you aren't actually executing the `ProcessMessageAsync` method, you're just passing a (strongly typed) reference to it (a "delegate" in C# parlance) into the RegisterMessageHandler, so that it can use it later.

You're just saying "here's the name of the method you need to call when it's time to process a message".

The message handler code will then call the message processing method at the appropriate time, and it will be responsible for setting suitable parameters at that moment.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/ for more info. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=netframework-4.8 as well.